# CFIF statement checking if database (MSSQL) is connecting or exists

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am trying to write an if statement in Coldfusion 16 to check to see if it can connect to the database or that it exists. If it can connect to the database then show the page otherwise show down for maintenance. How should I just check to make sure the database is up? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
<cfquery name="DBUP" datasource="datasource"> 
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.Entry 
</cfquery> 

<cfif DBUP>
 Show Page
<cfelse>
 Show Down For Maintenance
</cfif>
```

Comment: You should wrap the cfquery tag in a try/catch block. If the database cannot be accessed an exception will likely be thrown.

Comment: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Error_Handling/  <<< Like @BernhardDöbler says, I'd go with the try/catch.

Comment: Probably put it in your `onRequest` just so it's in a nice place you can find again rather than putting it in more than one page.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by "or that **it** exists". Are you referring to the database, a specific table, ... and why wouldn't either of those exist? Also, a query to check database accessibility should be kept short and sweet, like `select getDate() as DateNow` for SQL Server, rather than selecting all rows from a table. The latter is wasted traffic bandwidth, since the results aren't actually used for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add it in Application.cfc onRequest method probably.

```
<cftry>
 <cfquery name="DBUP" datasource="datasource"> 
  SELECT ID
  FROM dbo.Entry 
  </cfquery>
<cfcatch type="any">
  Show DOwn For Maintenance
   <!---everything optional below this line--->
   <!---can show some custom message---> 
  <cfinclude template="errorMsg.cfm">
  <!---stop the processing further--->
  <cfabort>
</cfcatch> 
</cftry>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't directly put a error message or file  in a catch statement. We should check one more condition ie) Error code is 0 or not. Imagine in some time the developer may give wrong query like undefined column or missing syntax etc... In that time also the catch will executed. So as per the requirement we have to check the datasource exists or not. If we want to check all type of issue means we no need of the error code conditions.

```
<cftry>
        <cfset showPage = true>
        <cfquery name="DBUP" datasource="datasource">
            SELECT ID FROM dbo.Entry 
        </cfquery>
        <cfcatch type="database">
            <!--- The error code 0 is mentioned Datasource could not be found/exits.  --->
            <cfif cfcatch.cause.errorcode eq 0 >
              <cfset showPage = false >
                <!--- Data source does not exists --->
            </cfif>

        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
```

Based on **showPage** value do you business logic here
....
....
....

Comment: Why not just catch the exception and handle it in OnError(), instead of try/catch on each page?

Comment: I'm not sure about whether they are using Application.cfc or not. If they use application cfc means the Yes, We can handle it in onError too.So I've given answer for simple CMS.

Comment: I don't know either, but would hope so given it's CF2016 ;-) If not, I'd recommend putting it in OnRequest(), as others are suggested. Otherwise, you'd need to add it to each page, which is very cumbersome.